# Using flask-security as a part of an REST API

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-security

I am currently in the process of building an REST API with flask-security. Fortunately flask-security has a lot of views and templates, which i won't need in my case. I am obviously not able to override them by reimplementing e.g. `@app.route('/login')` with my own logic.

So the simple question is, how do i disable all the views from flask-security which returns a template?

Comment: Why do you use Flask-Security if you don't need the views? Isn't Flask-Login enough?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, you may have a point. Can i use the roles feature separately?

Comment: Or would that be flask-user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can disable directly because none of the flask exposed APIs have disabled state. You can customize the views like this below sample:

Here is the link for reference: [Flask Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html)

```
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

# This processor is added to all templates
@security.context_processor
def security_context_processor():
    return dict(hello="world")

# This processor is added to only the register view
@security.register_context_processor
def security_register_processor():
    return dict(something="else")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand. But i cannot tear down the template/view? I do not want pages like the one on the login to be accessed as i want to run pure REST API style.

Comment: I believe you should only use Flask login then instead of Flask-security because you do not want to deal with the views directly.